# Angular2 material npm dependencies

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, angular2-directives

I have the following dependencies in my package.json for npm to find and install.

```
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1"
"angular-material": "^1.1.1"
```

In order to use the latest one's what should I specify?
The reason I am looking to use this for its support against NVDA and JAWS with IE / FF / Chrome (on Windows) as specified in the below link.

The ones that I am looking to use is as below.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/material2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2.0.0-beta.3` is the latest one right now. To be clear, that is [angular material 2](https://github.com/angular/material2), which is a completely separate framework from [angular material 1](https://github.com/angular/material). If you are using angular 2, you have to use angular material 2. So you cannot have `angular-material` in your `package.json`.

Comment: So, in this case what should i change it to upgrade "@angular/material": and "angular-material":

Comment: @user3910446 change `"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1"` to `"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.3"` (and then rerun `npm install`), and get rid of the other line since you can't use angular material 1 with angular 2.

Comment: Ok. That helps to understand but may I know what is the difference between the notations "@angular/material": and "angular-material":  ?

Comment: @BalajiK Angular has recently adopted using the [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) functionality of npm. That's what the at sign is referring to. From a consumer perspective, the only difference with scoped packages is they get installed to a subdirectory within the scope (`node_packages/@angular/material` instead of `node_packages/material`), which also means you have to include the scope name when requiring them (`require('@angular/material')`), but otherwise they're the same as regular packages.